# PHP ajax call failure

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am new to ajax and trying to create AJAX->PHP connection. I am using the following code

file1.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<input type="text" id='demo'>
<input type="button" onclick='ajaxCall()' value='23' >
<script>
function ajaxCall()
{
document.getElementById('demo').value="343434";   
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if(xmlhttp.requeststate==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById('demo').value="4444343434";   
    document.getElementById('demo').value=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
 }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the corresponding test.php

```
<?php
echo "me";
?>
```

Now when I click the button, the value of textbox is changing to 343434 but not changing on AJAX call, even it does not change to 4444343434. I'm currently runnning php 5.5.6 on ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Comment: Since you included jquery, use jquery's Ajax method rather than writing the Ajax manually with `new XMLHttpRequest` and so on.

Comment: indeed. use jquery's own ajax functions. it'll add in the error handling which you're lacking. Your code simply assumes everything will always succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `xmlhttp.requeststate` to `xmlhttp.readyState`

Try use the following crossbrowsing function

```
function getXmlHttp(){
  var xmlhttp;
  try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (E) {
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
  }
  if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}
```

And change `xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` to `xmlhttp = new getXmlHttp();`

And this work without jQuery.

Comment: I wouldn't go to the effort of supporting such ancient versions of IE in most cases.

Comment: This worked, can you please tell me what was wrong with my approach?

Comment: There is no `requeststate` property in `XMLHttpRequest`. Just `readyState`, `status` and `onreadystatechange`. Read more on http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp